# Laravel send email with error mkdir() : too many links

Tags: laravel, email

Our website is sending about 2000 emails to our customer daily, recently, it started to fail sending the email with the error message "mkdir() : too many links" .

The website is build with laravel framework and we are using the laravel Mail class to send the email.

Initially, when this error occur, we are able to solve it by clearing the laravel cache with the command `php artisan cache:clear`. The laravel `CACHE_DRIVER` is using `file`.

We tried to change it to use REDIS, and it works , however it didn't last long until the error `mkdir() : too many links` come back again.

How can we resolve this issue long term?

Comment: is it shared hosting? shared hosting is bad for these. might be some kind of permission issue or disk bus full.

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko not on a shared hosting. It is in a VPS. We have full control over the server and also SSH access. I don't think it's a permission issue. As the problem resolved after we cleared the laravel cache. But then it will come back again. Probably some Disk Full issue, however, we changed it to use redis and it still have the same problem.